# ReactJS: parsing csv date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to visualize some stock price data off a local csv. Sample row from the csv after successfully loading:

```
{Date: "2018-07-18", Open: "3251.280029", High: "3258.929932", Low: "3239.929932", Close: "3240.500000", …}
```

(some columns ommitted because I'll only show `Date` on the horizontal axis and `Close` on the vertical axis of a line chart anyway.)

I'm using `victory`, modifying their [line chart example](https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/gallery/brush-zoom/). Their `VictoryLine` element requires `data` to be in the following format:

```
const testData = [
  { newDate: new Date(2017, 1, 1), b: 125 },
  { newDate: new Date(2017, 3, 1), b: 257 },
  { newDate: new Date(2017, 6, 1), b: 345 },
  { newDate: new Date(2017, 9, 1), b: 515 },
  { newDate: new Date(2018, 12, 1), b: 132 },
  { newDate: new Date(2018, 3, 1), b: 305 },
  { newDate: new Date(2018, 6, 1), b: 270 },
  { newDate: new Date(2018, 9, 1), b: 300 },
  { newDate: new Date(2018, 12, 1), b: 320 },
]
```

I got a small script (tested and verified working on `node`) to add a `newDate` to each row, which is the ES6 `Date` representation of the yyyy-mm-dd date string:

```
var arr1 = [
    {"Date": "2017-04-15", "Price":"300"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-16", "Price":"310"},
    {"Date": "2017-04-17", "Price":"320"},
]

// add new column directly to arr1
arr1.forEach(o => o.newDate = new Date(o.Date));
```

So where do I implement that logic of creating the `newDate` column, inside my `App.js`? I've tried a few entry points, but none worked, with some unhelpful error messages:

- within `componentDidMount`: not sure how to execute, say, an
  `addNewDateColumn` function within a `.then()`.
- within `render(){}`,
  but before `return()`: didn't work because I'd have to add `newDate`,
  *then* proc this.setState()

For completeness, the full `App.js` (no child components) is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { VictoryChart, VictoryZoomContainer, VictoryLine, VictoryAxis, VictoryBrushContainer } from 'victory';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
// Sample data in local csv
import data from "./STI-small.csv"

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      zoomDomain: {x: [new Date(2017, 1, 1), new Date(2018, 12, 1)]},
      plotData: {}
    }
    this.handleZoom = this.handleZoom.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    d3.csv(data).then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }).catch(function(err) {
      throw err;
    }).then(data =>{this.setState({plotData:data})})
  }

  handleZoom(domain) {
    this.setState({ zoomDomain : domain })
  }

  render() {
    const testData = [
      { newDate: new Date(2017, 1, 1), b: 125 },
      { newDate: new Date(2017, 3, 1), b: 257 },
      { newDate: new Date(2017, 6, 1), b: 345 },
      { newDate: new Date(2017, 9, 1), b: 515 },
      { newDate: new Date(2018, 12, 1), b: 132 },
      { newDate: new Date(2018, 3, 1), b: 305 },
      { newDate: new Date(2018, 6, 1), b: 270 },
      { newDate: new Date(2018, 9, 1), b: 300 },
      { newDate: new Date(2018, 12, 1), b: 320 },
    ]

    return (
      <div>
        <VictoryChart width={600} height={200} scale={{x:"time"}}
        containerComponent = {
          <VictoryZoomContainer 
          zoomDimension="x"
          zoomDomain={this.state.zoomDomain}
          onZoomDomainChange={this.handleZoom.bind(this)}
        />}
        >

          <VictoryLine style={{ data: {stroke:"tomato"} }}
            data={testData}
            x="newDate"
            y="b"
          />
          </VictoryChart>

        <VictoryChart
          padding={{top:0, left:50, right:50, bottom:30}}
          width={600} height={100} scale={{ x:"time" }}
          containerComponent={
            <VictoryBrushContainer 
            brushDimension="x"
            brushDomain={this.state.zoomDomain}
            onBrushDomainChange={this.handleZoom.bind(this)}/>
          }>
          <VictoryAxis tickFormat={(x) => new Date(x).getFullYear()}
          />
          <VictoryLine
          style={{data:{stroke:"tomato"}}}
          data={testData}
          x="newDate"
          y="b"
          />
        </VictoryChart>
      </div>
    )}
}
export default App;
```

Some rows from the csv:

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Adj Close,Volume
2017-09-29,3222.719971,3225.260010,3200.729980,3219.909912,3219.909912,237131000
2017-10-02,3233.949951,3264.889893,3231.229980,3262.100098,3262.100098,159092800
2017-10-03,3269.489990,3270.080078,3232.060059,3246.080078,3246.080078,175651200
2017-10-04,3245.350098,3247.020020,3230.810059,3236.649902,3236.649902,208823200
```

Comment: Can you provide the csv file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Def a global function to parse:

```
function parseData(myInput) {
  // 1. Convert object of objects into array of objects
  // create new keys
  // Filter out for date range > 2016 for now
  let newArray = []
  for (var key in myInput) {
      if (myInput.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          const newRow = Object.assign({"newDate": new Date(key)}, {"Date":key}, {"Year":key.split("-")[0]}, myInput[key])
          if (parseInt(newRow["Year"])>2016) {
            newArray.push(newRow)
          }
      }
  }

  return newArray
}
```

Then call `parseData` in componentDidMount() with `.then(data => parseData(data))`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `moment.js` for date manipulations

`npm install moment --save`

`import Moment from 'moment'`

`const date = new Moment('2014-04-03')`

Also if the format of the date is not YYYY-DD-MM, you can always provide a format when creating a date

`const date = new Moment('12-31-2019', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

```
<VictoryAxis
  tickFormat={x => new Moment(x).format('YYYY')}
  fixLabelOverlap
/>
```